# Is it possible to view who has pushed a new branch to a remote?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I would like to know, if it possible to find out who has pushed a new branch into a remote repository on GitHub?

The problem is that the branch was created by checking out from existing master branch's commit that was made by one developer, so when I select the new branch in "Code" tab I see that he authored the last commit (which is in master branch), but actually he didn't push the new branch.

To bring a clarity to my situation, here is an illustration of what I mean

```
                                      master
                                        |
  --*---*----*--      ...........     --*
                                        |
                                    new branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access this information through the GitHub **[Events](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events)** API.

- **Syntax:** `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/events`
- **Example:** `https://api.github.com/users/libgit2/events`

This will return a JSON array of events. In order to discover who pushed to this repository, you'll have to filter those events and only examine those which `type` property equals `"PushEvent"`. The `actor` property will contain details about the pusher.

Below a sample of such a `PushEvent`

```
{
   id:"1842109394",
   type:"PushEvent",
   actor:{
      id:39902,
      login:"ben",
      gravatar_id:"0d410939c9e80980cf0430772567dfb4",
      url:"https://api.github.com/users/ben",
      avatar_url:"https://2.gravatar.com/avatar/0d410939c9e80980cf0430772567dfb4?d=https%3A%2F%2Fa248.e.akamai.net%2Fassets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png"
   },
   repo:{
      id:901662,
      name:"libgit2/libgit2",
      url:"https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2"
   },
   payload:{
      push_id:235346159,
      size:1,
      distinct_size:1,
      ref:"refs/heads/redir-refactor",
      head:"b59344bf83049a5639c32ab52efceea2eec9484b",
      before:"256961e45d574ace62a7a7d13b697aa05e8a9466",
      commits:[
         {
            sha:"b59344bf83049a5639c32ab52efceea2eec9484b",
            author:{
               email:"bs@github.com",
               name:"Ben Straub"
            },
            message:"Tighten up url-connection utility",
            distinct:true,
            url:"https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2/commits/b59344bf83049a5639c32ab52efceea2eec9484b"
         }
      ]
   },
   public:true,
   created_at:"2013-09-26T23:56:59Z",
   org:{
      id:394745,
      login:"libgit2",
      gravatar_id:"1c56acccc41c591705dc92da5f6ab603",
      url:"https://api.github.com/orgs/libgit2",
      avatar_url:"https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/1c56acccc41c591705dc92da5f6ab603?d=https%3A%2F%2Fa248.e.akamai.net%2Fassets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-org-420.png"
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's interesting. But if I understand correctly, it works only for public repositories and I have a private one.

Comment: You'll need to be authenticated to retrieve data related to private repositories (see http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)

Answer (score 2):

No, Git does not by itself save any information about "who" pushed a commit, because the systems for authenticating and identifying oneself when pushing are outside the scope of Git.

Rather, you'd have to check the server logs for what happened at the time of the push. If pushing happens over SSH, check your syslog; if they happen over HTTP, check the server's access log.

Of course, you could create hook scripts in your central repository for logging pushes according to your setup's conception of identification, but I'm guessing the point of this question is that you want to find out about a historical event in this case, rather than proofing for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if I can find repository access log on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git log remotename/branchname
```

This will show the log of a given remote branch in that repository.

Comment: Yeah, that's great, but this will give me only a log history for commits starting from the last one made in "master" branch (as considerable branch was created from "master" branch) by other developer and I need to know who exactly pushed this new branch